# need help for dice throwing combinations

Tags: vba, excel

i'm working on a vba program
the program goes something like this:

you know the number that you roll with two dice's (the number wich is rolled is to be filled in by the user)
then the program needs to display every possible combination that can be thrown

so for 2 it should be 1 and 1
for 3 it should be 1 and 2 but also 2 and 1 and so on.

as of now i am trying to do it with random numbers but when i determine that the x value may not be equal to my x1 value the programm freezes.

would somebody be so kind to help me out here? :D

thanks in advance.

my program so far:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim invoer As Integer

    invoer = Range("A1")

    If invoer < "2" Then
        MsgBox ("kan niet gegooid worden")
    End If

    If invoer > "12" Then
        MsgBox ("kan niet gegooid worden")
    End If

    Do
        x = Int((6 * Rnd) + 1)
        y = Int((6 * Rnd) + 1)
    Loop Until x + y = invoer

    If x + y = invoer Then
        Range("a3") = x
        Range("b3") = y
        Do
            x1 = Int((6 * Rnd) + 1)
            y1 = Int((6 * Rnd) + 1)
        Loop Until (x1 = Not x) + (y1 = Not y) = invoer
        If x1 = Not x Then
            Range("a4") = x1
            Range("b4") = y1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Does _would somebody be so kind to help me out here_ stand for _would anybody be so kind to write the code for me_? Or you have some code to show?

Comment: **Help us to help you.** Post your current code.

Comment: hi matteo, i have added the code i would like to get some tips on how to do this, if somebody would like to write the code for me it would be much appriciated. but tips are welcome too, because i want to be able to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to complicate with the concept of RND(), this is very simple maths. You need to loop from 2 (which is the minimum) to 12 (the maximum) on a normal two die. on every increment you just take away form the other die.

In my very honest opinion, this is all that is needed. Good luck.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim inVoer As Integer, dCtr As Integer
    Dim rCtr As Integer

    'Reads the Number from the Cell
    inVoer = Range("A1")

    'Checks if the number entered is valid for a two die combination.
    'The minimum you can get on a two die is 2, and the maximum is 12.
    If inVoer <= 1 Or inVoer > 12 Then
        'If anything not between 2 and 12, a message is displayed for the user. 
        MsgBox ("kan niet gegooid worden")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'This counter is used to get the next ROW to print the result to.
    rCtr = 2

    'Loop from the minimum, to the number entered in the CELL.
    For dCtr = 2 To inVoer
        'As each die can have only 1 to 6, we need to make sure the numbers generated,
        'are between 1 and 6, anything greater is not desired.
        If (dCtr - 1 <= 6) And (inVoer - dCtr + 1) <= 6 Then
            'The Logic - If die 1 has 'x', die 2 'y'. x + y should give inVoer.
            'So -> dCtr - 1 + inVoer - dCtr + 1 = inVoer

            'dCtr - 1 will give the result of the first die.
            Range("A" & rCtr + 1) = dCtr - 1

            'inVoer - dCtr - 1, gives the result of the other die.
            Range("B" & rCtr + 1) = inVoer - dCtr + 1

            'Increment the ROW Counter
            rCtr = rCtr + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear paul, thank you! it almost works perfect exept  for when i throw 8 or higher but i will try to fix this myself. but thank you very much!

Comment: well the number i range "A" may not go higher then 6 or lower then 1

Comment: same as for range "B"

Comment: because else the program says i can throw 11 with one dice

Comment: paul, it works fine exept when the filled in number goes above 7 because then is starts as follows: throw 8 combination: 7,1 6,2 etc.

Comment: Oh okay, now I see what you mean. So sorry. Try the edited code.

Comment: I have added comments to explain :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim inVoer As Integer, dCtr As Integer, cCtr As Integer
 For dCtr = 2 To inVoer

       'As each die can have only 1 to 6, we need to make sure the numbers generated,
       'are between 1 and 6, anything greater is not desired.
       If (dCtr - 1 <= 6) And (inVoer - dCtr + 1) <= 6 Then
           'The Logic - If die 1 has 'x', die 2 'y'. x + y should give inVoer.
           'So -> dCtr - 1 + inVoer - dCtr + 1 = inVoer

           'dCtr - 1 will give the result of the first die.
           Range("A" & rCtr + 1) = dCtr - 1

           'inVoer - dCtr - 1, gives the result of the other die.
           Range("B" & rCtr + 1) = inVoer - dCtr + 1

           'Increment the ROW Counter
            rCtr = rCtr + 1



       End If

       'trying a new next with dCtr 3 to inVoer, so new formula x + y + z?


   For cCtr = 3 To inVoer

   If (cCtr - 2 <= 6) And (dCtr - 1 <= 6) And (inVoer - (cCtr + 2 - dCtr + 1 / 2)) <= 6 Then

   If ((cCtr - 2 <= 6) And (dCtr - 1 <= 6)) = inVoer Then Exit For

   Range("A" & rCtr + 1) = dCtr - 1

   Range("B" & rCtr + 1) = cCtr - 2
    'this can give a negative number
   Range("C" & rCtr + 1) = inVoer - cCtr + 2 - dCtr + 1

   rCtr = rCtr + 1


   End If
   Next

   Next
```

So I set a new cCtr as integer to give myself a way to calculate in such way that invoer is my output.

At this point you can see the problem is that my inVoer in range C has a change of becoming negative. If anyone could help me fix that. I can finish it! :)